# SSH: Why doesn't "get" command work?

Tags: ssh

I need to download some files using `ssh`, but I'm not able to get them.

The first command I try is:

```
ssh get folderName
```

...and nothing happens.

The second command is:

```
ssh get *
```

...and for each file I get the following error message:

```
ERROR [/path/to/file.png]: not an SCCS file (co1)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**There's no such thing as an `ssh get` command. You probably wanted `scp`, or maybe `sftp`.**

`ssh` is the "Secure SHell". It's for securely connecting to a command shell on remote machines (think of it like secure `telnet`), or sending shell commands to be executed by another machine. `ssh` itself is not for copying files. `ssh` has a companion program `scp` (Secure CoPy) for securely retrieving files from another machine. The syntax for `scp` goes like this:

```
scp -r user@host:/path/to/folderName .
```

(The `-r` is for "recursive", which means it gets the target folder and its entire contents, not just the target folder itself.)

**So what happened before?**
The command you were running, well, either you had a config file set up to define the remote host to connect to, and possibly the user name to connect as, or you left out part of the command. It would canonically be written like this:

```
ssh user@host get folderName
```

Which means you were opening a secure shell on the remote host, and issuing the `get` shell command over there, with argument `folderName`. I don't have a `get` command on my system, but some brief Googling reveals that some ancient source code control systems such as SCCS and RCS may have had a `get` command, which fits with the error message you saw. I think you were accidentally invoking the SCCS or RCS `get` command on the remote system, but since the `folderName` wasn't a recognized source code repository format, it failed.

Comment: so, is scp always working when ssh is working ? (do providers providing ssh access usually also provide scp access ?)

Comment: Yes, scp is pretty much everywhere that ssh is. It is installed and enabled by default when you enable ssh, it takes extra work to disable it, and most people don't have a good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of Wget

just add a "W"